# If spontaneous symmetry breaking only occurs in infinite systems, why do we observe similar effects in finite systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, symmetry-breaking

## Background

### No SSB in finite systems

Consider a system interacting with a heat bath at inverse temperature $\beta$, with the resultant dynamics of the system described by a Liouvillian superoperator $\mathcal{L}$. If this system is finite, then under fairly general conditions on $\mathcal{L}$, we expect the equilibrium state $\rho$, meaning $\mathcal{L}(\rho) = 0$, to be uniquely given by the Gibbs state

$$
\rho_{\mathrm{gibbs}} = \dfrac{e^{-\beta H}}{\mathrm{Tr}\left[ e^{-\beta H} \right]},
$$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the symmetry group of the Hamiltonian, meaning there is a unitary representation $U$ of $\mathcal{G}$ such that $[H, U(g)] = 0$ for all $g \in \mathcal{G}$. It is clear that we also have $[\rho_{\mathrm{gibbs}}, U(g)] = 0$, so the Gibbs state preserves all the symmetries of the Hamiltonian. In this sense, it seems that there cannot be spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) in *finite* systems.

### SSB in infinite systems (and KMS states)

The typical narrative then proceeds to say that, in fact, SSB can occur, but only in *infinite* systems. Here there is no guarantee that $e^{-\beta H}$ is trace-class, so in general the Gibbs state is not well defined. To extend the notion of a "thermal" state to infinite systems, one usually defines the so-called KMS states. These are the states $\phi$ which satisfy the KMS condition, which can (informally) be stated as

$$
\langle A (t) B \rangle_{\phi} = \langle B(t + i\beta) A \rangle_{\phi},
$$

for all operators $A$ and $B$ in the operator algebra, where $\langle \cdot \rangle_{\phi}$ indicates an expectation value with respect to the state $\phi$. (I omit all $C^{*}$-algebraic details here for brevity.)

There is a large body of literature showing that KMS states preserve the properties that we consider key to the definition of a thermal state, such as being equilibrium states, but remain well-defined for infinite systems.

For finite systems, I believe the KMS condition *uniquely* specifies a state: the Gibbs state. However, for infinite systems this is not necessarily the case, and, roughly speaking, SSB occurs when there are multiple KMS states, each of which is not preserved by the symmetry group of the Hamiltonian.

## Question

Both experiments and numerical simulations show systems with behaviour that seems very similar to that of SSB (ferromagnets exist!). However, these real-world systems are clearly finite, so the above arguments would suggest that they cannot truly display SSB. What is the explanation for this discrepancy?

## Thoughts on an answer

Though finite, real-world experiments can often by fairly effectively described by taking the infinite size limit. If this is appropriate, then perhaps the dynamics of these large finite systems can be well approximated by infinite systems, at least up to some large timescale $\tau$ which presumably grows quickly with system size. Then we might expect these finite systems to display signatures of SSB over the timescale $\tau$, after which they will decay to the Gibbs state and the symmetry will be restored. If this is along the right lines, can any of this be made precise?

Comment: Some quick thoughts: 1) the absolute ground state is a macroscopic superposition of the symmetry breaking state. 2). The tinyest amount of coupling will destroy coherence for this cat state 3) my guess is the smallest temperature gibs state is a mixed state of the symmetry broken states, so over all its symmetric. This is consistent with experiments where you don’t know how the symmetry is broken before hand.  I don’t know how to prove this. It might just be physically the macroscopic tunneling time diverges and there is never a true gibs state thermalization

Comment: Is this about quantum, classical, or both?

Comment: This sounds like excess mathematical formalism clouding a very simple physical point. Forget all about Liouvillian superoperators, KMS states, and $C^*$ algebras. The point is that a big system has degenerate ground states with high energy barriers between them. In the statistical mechanical case, the timescale for thermal fluctuations between them is very small. In the quantum case, a superposition of them is not stable, and decoheres immediately. So in either case you see the system in a single, symmetry broken state.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch , I believe the KMS formalism applies equally well to the quantum and classical cases, so in principle I mean both. However, I'm still a relative pedestrian when it comes to SSB, quantum or classical, so I'd also be interested in answers that only apply to one or the other.

Comment: @knzhou , do you not agree there is a qualitative difference between finite and infinite systems when it comes to SSB? Apologies if the mathematics I mentioned obfuscated the point, but I believe the underlying logic is correct. Regarding your point about unstable cat states, I have two points of confusion: i) how does this extend to finite temperature? ii) even at 0T, why should the equilibrium state be a pure state? Could it not be an equal mixture of the ground states, which would be symmetry-invariant? Indeed this is what you get if you take the limit $\beta \to \infty$ of the Gibbs state.

Comment: @OliverLunt No, there's no qualitative difference between finite and infinite systems, because every physical property of an infinite system should be approximated arbitrarily well by a sufficiently large finite one. If you did find a quantity that didn't obey this rule (i.e. where the infinite case would look completely different from any finite case, no matter how large), then it would be irrelevant for all physical purposes because no infinite systems exist.

Comment: In the classical case, you can't mix the ground states; the magnet points either this way or that way. In the quantum case any superposition of the two will immediately decohere upon interaction with just about anything else. (Or, said another way, any charged particle passing by will "measure" the direction and hence collapse the superposition.) At finite temperature tunneling between the ground states by thermal fluctuations becomes possible, but that doesn't change the conclusions much.

Comment: @knzhou , what you say about finite vs infinite systems seems sensible. However, the argument I gave for "no SSB in finite systems" is very simple. Are you saying there is a flaw in this argument?

Comment: @knzhou , I agree that a pure state consisting of a symmetric superposition of symmetry-breaking states should be unstable to decoherence. However, as I mentioned in my previous comment, I'm not sure why the equilibrium state (which is the relevant one for SSB, right?) should be a pure state, rather than a mixed state. Taking the limit $\beta \to \infty$ of the Gibbs state gives you an equal mixed state of all the ground states, which is invariant under any symmetry of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @OliverLunt Yes, but it's one thing to mathematically postulate the system is in the Gibbs state, and quite another thing to _put_ it in that state in the lab. It's like asking somebody to prepare a Schrodinger's cat. The mathematical formalism doesn't account for _any_ external perturbations.

Comment: @knzhou I'm not sure what you mean. There is ample experimental evidence to suggest that the state of a system left to thermally equilibrate will be (well approximated by) a Gibbs distribution.

Comment: @OliverLunt At high temperatures, sure. But for low temperatures the Gibbs distribution describes a system in thermal equilibrium with a ideal thermal bath at zero temperature -- that is, a perfectly isolated system. That's the part that's unrealistic. No matter what the temperature is, the Gibbs distribution cannot account for the field from the fridge magnet in the other room, or for somebody turning on a microwave down the hall, or an impurity in the crystal, because these are not part of an ideal thermal bath. For lower temperatures these effects get relatively more important.

Comment: Here's another way to put it. All states are really pure; you only use mixed states when you're missing information (i.e. about the system itself, or perhaps the state of the environment). So maybe you can say the $T = 0$ state of a magnet is mixed, because some undergrad cooled down the magnet for you and you don't know which way it ended up pointing. But you can just come into the room and _look_ at it, in which case you can treat it as a pure state. (This is simply yet another way of phrasing the decoherence/measurement thing I said earlier.)

Comment: While it makes little difference to physical system, mathematically infinite and finite systems are very different. For finite systems, dechorence doesn’t exist, there is always a recurrence time where the original state reappears.  This time goes to infinity as system size increases and subsystems can appear to thermalize as they do for infinite systems. But infinite systems the information about the initial state spreads to infinity and the system never recurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question exactly is addressed and rigorously treated by [N.P. Landsman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4473v2). The explanation is that in the large $N$ limit the symmetric ground state becomes exponentially sensitive to asymmetric perturbations, while the first excited states, although unstable, become very close in energy to the symmetric state and decay exponentially slowly in any direction, thus the system dynamically finds itself in a symmetry broken state already at a finite by very large $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this matches your puzzle, but: when you write something like $[\rho, \mathcal{G}]$, you are thinking about measuring the symmetry existence by looking at the expectation value of the operator itself. However, in completely quantum sense, you should define the symmetry with the expectation of correlators other than operators themselves.

You might find the note of Lec.1 here helpful, which used transverse Ising model as an example, and the SB definition is mentioned on Pg.9

https://learning-modules.mit.edu/materials/index.html?uuid=/course/8/fa17/8.513#materials

Comment: Hi, I know this is a while ago but would you mind sharing the lecture note you had? I couldn't access this myself... Thanks in advance.